# compare files in order to extract text from multiline regex:compare-object,hastables or psobject?

Tags: regex, powershell

The beginning of my code is the following:

```
$file1 = "G:\test_powershell_subtitle\The Big Bang Theory - 08x06 - french.srt"
$file2 = "G:\test_powershell_subtitle\The Big Bang Theory - 08x06 - english.srt"
$text1 =get-content($file1)  -Raw
$text2 =get-content($file2)  -Raw


$regex = [regex]'(?m)(?<sequence>\d+)\r\n(?<timecode>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\r\n(?<text>[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n)'

$matches = $regex.Matches($text1)
 $matches  |% {
    if ($_ -match $regex){

    new-object psobject -property @{

                    sequence = $matches['sequence']
                    timecode = $matches['timecode']
                    text     = $matches['text']

                    }
      } 
}
```

The output:

```
timecode                                    sequence                text                            
----                                         --------                ----                                       
00:00:02,880 --> 00:00:04,146                1                       I like your suit....       
00:00:04,148 --> 00:00:06,699                2                       Oh, thanks. Got a ...          
00:00:06,701 --> 00:00:08,651                3                       How does it feel knowing...     
00:00:08,653 --> 00:00:10,786                4                       is to go out...
```

.

My goal is to merge the subtitles of different languages ​​according to the timecode to a single file.

What is the best way to proceed? compare-object,hastables or psobject?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You want to combine the strings of english and french so that both will be displayed simultaneously then? Should be able to use `Group-Object timecode` on both objects created which will combine the timecodes that are the same. Then you could break out the text array that is created to massage it and output to a new file

Comment: You could have other issues to be concered about like what happens when there is not match of time and who should take precendence. Also the subtitles need to match timecodes to the millisecond so need to come from the same source. The latter usually should not be an issue.

Comment: @peterYou want to combine the strings of english and french so that both will be displayed simultaneously then?

Comment: Do you not understand the question? I'm basically asking for desired output. So while the video plays you want to see both subtitle at once. The string need to be combined yes?

Comment: @Matt  "You want to combine the strings of english and french so that both will be displayed simultaneously then?"  You understand what i want but i don't know how use "group-object" to achieve the result. sorry for the last post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have some more work ahead of you but this should be enough to satisfy the question at hand. `Group-Object` is the way to go I think for this one.

```
function Convert-SubtitlesToObject{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [String]
        $Path
    )
    $regex = [regex]'(?m)(?<sequence>\d+)\r\n(?<timecode>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\r\n(?<text>[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n)'
    $text = Get-Content($Path) -Raw
    $matches = $regex.Matches($text)
    $matches | Where-Object{$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object{ 
        [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
            sequence = $matches['sequence']
            timecode = $matches['timecode']
            text     = $matches['text']
        }
    }
}

$englishSubs = Convert-SubtitlesToObject -Path 'C:\temp\put\The Big Bang Theory - 8x06 - The Expedition Approximation.HDTV.LOL.HI.en.srt'
$frenchSubs = Convert-SubtitlesToObject -Path 'C:\temp\put\The Big Bang Theory - 8x06 - The Expedition Approximation.HDTV.LOL.fr.srt'

$collection = @()
$collection += $englishSubs
$collection += $frenchSubs 

$sequence = 0
$collection | Group-Object timecode | Select-Object Name,@{l="Text";e={$_.Group.Text}} | ForEach-Object{
    $sequence++
    Write-Output "$sequence`r`n$($_.Name)`r`n$($_.Text)"
}
```

I converted you code into a function since you will be calling that for all files. Run this for both english and french subs and put them into the larger `$collection`. Call `Group-Object` on that collection and group them by the timecode. Take that data and expand the text into a single field. After all that take the collect the output to best imitate a subtitle file. You need to watch out for timecodes that dont match but I leave that to you as to what you will do in that situation.

Here is some sample output which you could pipe into `Out-File` or `Add-Content`:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,800
English Subtitles (HI) 
[MP4] The Big Bang Theory S08E06 (720p) The Expedition Approximation HDTV [KoTuWa]


2
00:00:02,880 --> 00:00:04,146
I like your suit.

 J'aime ton tailleur.


3
00:00:04,148 --> 00:00:06,699
Oh, thanks. Got a couple
new outfits for work.

 Merci.
J'en ai acheté pour le boulot.
```

**Disclaimer**

I know some PowerShell. I know jack about subtitle file formats.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply . I tried to find a solution by myself. It is not complete , especially if the timecode are not identical . Yours is better.

Here is my solution.

```
function Convert-SubtitlesToObject{
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [String]
    $Path
)
$regex = [regex]'(?m)(?<sequence>\d+)\r\n(?<timecode>(?<t1>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\r\n(?<text>[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n)'
$text = Get-Content($Path) -Raw
$matches = $regex.Matches($text)
$matches | Where-Object{$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object{ 
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        sequence = $matches['sequence']
        timecode = $matches['timecode']
        text     = $matches['text']
    }
}
}

$englishSubs = Convert-SubtitlesToObject -Path 'G:\test_powershell_subtitle\The Big Bang Theory - 08x06 - english.srt'
$frenchSubs = Convert-SubtitlesToObject -Path 'G:\test_powershell_subtitle\The Big Bang Theory - 08x06 - french.srt'

$temp = Compare-Object $frenchSubs $englishSubs -property sequence,timecode,text

 $subtitles=$temp | Group-Object -Property timecode| % { 
    [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
            seq=$_.group[1].sequence;
            time=$_.name;
            string=$_.group[0].text+$_.group[1].text}}  

#Construct an out-array to use for data export
$OutArray = @()
$Outarray +=$subtitles.psobject.properties | % {$_.value} # each object's fields

# get the index for element that is -eq to SyncRoot
# The SyncRoot is returning the collection

$index = 0..($outarray.psobject.properties.name.length - 1) | ? {$outarray.psobject.properties.name[$_] -eq "SyncRoot"}

for($i = $index; $i -le $OutArray.matches.count; $i++){

Write-Output "$($outarray[$i].seq)`r`n$($outarray[$i].time)`r`n$($outarray[$i].string)`r`n"
}
```